# Changing radius for rounded corners in tikz \graph

Tags: tikz-graphs

I'd like to specify the radius of `rounded corner`s in my `\graph`.
I know I can change the radius of a `rounded corner` with an explicit `\draw` command, but I haven't seen a way to do it in a graph.

The solution might be something simple, but I'm very new to LaTex and Tikz...

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, graphs, matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [
  point/.style={ circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2pt, fill=red },
  graphs/every graph/.style = { edges=rounded corners },
  hv path/.style = {to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}},
  >= stealth, black!50, text = black, thick,
]

\matrix (m) [row sep=1cm, column sep=1cm]
  {
    &
    \node (p1) [point] {}; &
    \\

    \node (p2) [point] {}; &
    &
    \\
  };
\graph [use existing nodes] {
  p2 --[hv path] p1
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! You are almost there. All I did was to change `edges=rounded corners` to `edges={rounded corners=5mm}`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, graphs, matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [
  point/.style={ circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2pt, fill=red },
  graphs/every graph/.style = { edges={rounded corners=5mm} },
  hv path/.style = {to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}},
  >= stealth, black!50, text = black, thick,
]

\matrix (m) [row sep=1cm, column sep=1cm]
  {
    &
    \node (p1) [point] {}; &
    \\

    \node (p2) [point] {}; &
    &
    \\
  };
\graph [use existing nodes] {
  p2 --[hv path] p1
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was guessing I might need some escape/quote mechanism to do "rounded corners=X", but am so new to latex I couldn't come up with a plausible guess. Thanks.

Comment: How should I have been able to figure that out?  Is that based on LaTex syntax or some feature of tikz?  I'm guessing LaTex, but confirmation would be helpful.

Comment: @TOertel Yes, to some extent it is "just" (La)TeX. `{` starts a group and `}` ends it. That is, if you want to have a subscript "k>0", you say `$A_{k>0}$` such that all of it becomes a subscript. The only additional information is how pgfkeys work, i.e. some of them have parameters, which are passed to them via `<key>=<parameter>`.